# Jquery - find classes of child id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
<div id=box1>
    <div id='1' class='product' style=""></div>
    <div id='2' class='product' style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id='3' class='product' style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
<div id=box2>
    <div id='4' class='product' style=""></div>
    <div id='5' class='product' style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id='6' class='product' style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
<div id=box3>
    <div id='7' class='product' style=""></div>
    <div id='8' class='product' style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id='9' class='product' style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is work exclusively with the elements from a particular box and ignore all other elements.

I understand I need to use child elements and this is what I currently have:

```
 $( "some-click-event" ).click(function() {
     var boxid = $(this).data("boxid"); //taken from the clicked element

        //Now I want to work exclusively with the particular box

        $("#" + boxid).children(function() {
            //Now I need to recurse through each box element  
            $( ".product" ).each(function( index ) {
                //Toggle display
            });
        });

    });
```

So my question is this: How do I target the specific box id?

Comment: Why do you have numbers as IDs

Comment: did you typo `'#' + boxId` instead of `'#box' + boxId` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method for this:

```
$("#box" + boxid).find( '.product' ).each(function() {
    //Toggle display 
    $( this ).toggle();
});
```

Comment: This did the job for my needs, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in the selector the boxid + class of the product inside:

```
$( "some-click-event" ).click(function() {
 var boxid = $(this).data("boxid"); //taken from the clicked element

    //Now I need to recurse through each box element  
     $("#" + boxid + " .product" ).each(function( index ) {
        //Toggle display
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select those products like this:

```
$("#box" + boxid + " > .product").toggle();
```

---

> Unless this was a typo, this wouldn't select anything based on your
>   html:

```
$("#" + boxid).children(function() {
```

---

> Even though you were in the context of looping through the children of
>   the previously selected element, this would select all elements
>   with the class `product` even if they weren't children of the
>   iterating element.

```
$( ".product" ).each(function( index ) {
```